# Replacing each number within an array with the maximum number up to that point

Tags: c++, arrays, mingw

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
ifstream f("date.in");
using namespace std;
int i;
int P(int a[100],int k,int max)
{
    max=a[1];
    for(i=2;i<=k;i++)
            if(a[i]>max)
               max=a[i];
    return max;
}
int main()
{
    int x,a[100],n;
    f>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        f>>a[i];
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
        a[i]=P(a,i,x);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
```

My "date.in" file consists of the following :

```
12

4 6 3 7 8 1 6 2 7 9 10 8
```

As the title states, the program should modify the array from within the file such that each number has the maximum value found in the array up to, and including, the position of that respective number. I've gone through it a hundred times but cannot figure out what's wrong with my code.

When compiled, I get the following:

```
4 6 3 7 8 8 6 8 7 9 10 10
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Wait, your code is wierd.... why would you code it like that?  That's slow!  This can be done in a single pass easily!

Comment: Your index starts with 1. It should be 0.

Comment: it was just the first method that came to mind, so I used it, because it doesn't have to be efficient and etc...I could've changed the method, but the fact that THIS code doesn't work intrigues me, so I stick with it and want to find out what's wrong, so I won't make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: Seems like you should only need one loop.  Your routine P has most of what you need -- all you need to do is to set the array element equal to max.  (Hint:  ALWAYS use `{}` brackets when you do a loop.  The code is easier to follow and you'll have fewer bugs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i;
```

Globals are usually a bad idea.  Because this loop:

```
for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    a[i]=P(a,i,x);
```

and this loop:

```
for(i=2;i<=k;i++)
        if(a[i]>max)
           max=a[i];
```

are running "at the same time", and thus `i` in the first one is NOT counting from `2` to `n` properly, it's only actually getting the first index and then the even indexes.  (Check your results, the even indexes are 100% correct: `x 6 x 7 x 8 x 8 x 9 x 10`).  If you use counters local to each loop: `for(int i=2; ...` then this problem wouldn't be happening.

Also your entire design is slow.  Not sure why you did it that way, because it can be done easily in a single pass: http://ideone.com/LmD0HX.
And use `<iostream>` not `<iostream.h>`. They're actually different files.

Comment: Yes that method is easier, but the instructions that I am following force me to use a subalgorithm. Thank you for the quick response, I understand what the issue was .

Comment: To be more specific about the last sentence, the .h versions of iostream and fstream are not standard headers.

Comment: @GîdeiCodrin: Here's a super abreviated form of the single pass:http://ideone.com/idFarS